# Error: Failed to lookup view "error" in views directory Node JS and Jquery Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, npm

I can't figure out the solution to this problem, even after looking over previous posts.

I am getting the error below:

> GET /public/stylesheets/nice-select.css 404 2.429 ms - 1594
>       Error: Failed to lookup view "error" in views directory "/home/nmysore/PhpstormProjects/Makerspace/express_example/views"
>           at EventEmitter.render (/home/nmysore/PhpstormProjects/Makerspace/express_example/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:580:17)
>           at ServerResponse.render (/home/nmysore/PhpstormProjects/Makerspace/express_example/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:971:7)
>           at /home/nmysore/PhpstormProjects/Makerspace/express_example/app.js:49:7
>           at Layer.handle_error (/home/nmysore/PhpstormProjects/Makerspace/express_example/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:71:5)
>           at trim_prefix (/home/nmysore/PhpstormProjects/Makerspace/express_example/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:315:13)
>           at /home/nmysore/PhpstormProjects/Makerspace/express_example/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
>           at Function.process_params (/home/nmysore/PhpstormProjects/Makerspace/express_example/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
>           at next (/home/nmysore/PhpstormProjects/Makerspace/express_example/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
>           at /home/nmysore/PhpstormProjects/Makerspace/express_example/app.js:38:3
>           at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/nmysore/PhpstormProjects/Makerspace/express_example/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)

I am trying to use some jQuery package to have nice animations when selecting elements, and using a node.js server.

http://hernansartorio.com/jQuery-nice-select/

My structure is currently:

[image: Structure]

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var stylus = require('stylus');

var index = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'html');

// unce(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })); 
app.use(cookieParser());    
app.use(stylus.middleware(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/users', users);

app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler 
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
 });

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

And inside my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="public/javascripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="public/javascripts/jquery.nice-select.js"></script>
<link rel = "stylesheet" href="public/stylesheets/nice-select.css">
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('select').niceSelect();
});
</script>
<body>
    <h1>My First Heading</h1>
    <p>My first paragraph.</p>
    <select name='Major'>
        <option disabled selected>Select Major</option>
        <option value="1">All Majors</option>
        <option value="2">Computer Science</option>
        <option value="3">Structural Engineering</option>
        <option value="4">Cognitive Science</option>
        <option value="5">Bioengineering</option>
        <option value="6">Electrical Engineering</option>
        <option value="7">Etc</option>
        <option value="8">Etc</option>
    </select>
</body>
</html>
```

I've tried a bunch of suggestions on previous threads, but the error is not going away.

Answer (score 1):

You're asking for the `error.html` view with this line:

`res.render('error');`

Yet it doesn't exist in the `views` folder. Add an `error.html` and it should render.